# How to remove blank lines in between data lines using python

Tags: python, string

I have a text file which has some inconsistent data. Like name with additional spaces, special char, etc I have removed that but I am not able to remove the blank lines in between two data lines

```
f = open("sample_data.txt", "rb")
print (f.next())

for x in f:
    new = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9,.]', "", x)
    print (new)
```

this is my input data:

[image: this is my input data]

this is output I am getting:

[image: this is output I am getting]

I want to delete lines 11,12,14&15

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Off-site links are not generally acceptable.  Images of text are *not* acceptable.

Comment: "Removing blank lines" means not printing such lines at all. Right now you're printing every line.

Comment: @mustaccio I want to eliminate blank lines were ever found in .txt file

Comment: Do you mean to prevent those blank lines from printing, or do you want to modify the file to remove those blank lines from the file? Your question is not clear as it stands, especially since your code deals only with printing.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yeah, I want to remove those blank lines from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about checking if `new` contains onlybefore printing? Would this work for you?

```
for x in f:
    new = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9,.]', "", x)

    if len(new.strip()) > 0:
        print(new)
```

---

It seems the lines are not really empty, they just have a number at the start and nothing else after that.

How about checking that the leght is greater than 2? That should avoid printing those lines that only have a number at the start.

```
for x in f:
    new = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9,.]', "", x)

    if len(new.strip()) > 2:
        print(new)
```

Comment: @Raif It is just printing twice and not removing the blank lines

Comment: @VibhorKarnawat I edited my answer. Does that help?

Comment: @VibhorKarnawat do you want to renumber the lines or keep the original numbers? Right now my code keeps the original numbers

Comment: No I want to keep the original number only thanks :)